# The Meran System plan of attack

Tags: opening, queens-gambit, slav-defense

I've recently started to play the triangle system against the Queen's gambit, and so far it is okay. I've extensive knowledge in the Noteboom variation, but the problem with it is that the variation can be easily be avoided by White (since it is such a sharp line).

So I decided to search for a fall back plan.

I mean, I've just been doing the automatic c5 counters when Noteboom was turned down, but I've stumbled across this system called the Meran system.

**Can you tell me the theory behind this system?**

On the surface it looks like Black is supposed to advance on the Queenside, but I'm fuzzy on the details, nor this "Anti-Meran".

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If black plays the triangle system againts the Queen's Gambit, white can (try to) transpose to the Semi-Slav defence: 1.d4 d5 2.c4 e6 3.Nc3 c6 4.e3 Nf6 5.Nf3 Nbd7.

The line 6.Bd3 dxc4 7.Bxc4 b5 is called the Meran. White can avoid this, by playing the Anti-Meran: 6.Qc2. A good summary can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-Slav_Defense).

According to the [Game Database of ChessTempo](http://chesstempo.com/game-database.html), 4....Nf6 and 5....Nbd7 are by far the most popular replies for black. The Semi-Slav is known to be a good and solid defence.

An alternative for black is 5....a6, which was played many times by Anand in his [WCC-match](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?tid=77342) against Gelfand.

An other idea is to transpose to the Stonewall. You can play 4....f5 immediately or wait a couple of moves like in the game [Kasimdzhanov-Grischuk](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1775842).

```
      [FEN ""]
      [StartPly "7"]

      1.d4 d5 2.c4 e6 3.Nc3 c6 4.e3 Nf6 (4...f5)(4...Nd7 5.Qc2 Nh6 6.Bd2 f5) 5.Nf3 Nbd7 (5...a6) 6.Bd3 (6.Qc2) dxc4 7.Bxc4 b5
```